how to instruct langchain UnstructuredPowerPointLoader to group data based on bounding box for powerpoint documents
While trying to create document loader using langchain UnstructuredPowerPointLoader, document is loaded by parsing the PPT content by traversing horizontally. This will cause problem for the cases where individual contexts on added inside rectangle shapes.
How to tweak UnstructuredPowerPointLoader to tag the contents present inside bounding boxes into one context ?
Please find the code used for creating document loader
from langchain_community.document_loaders import UnstructuredPowerPointLoader
from langchain.vectorstores import utils as chromautils
loader = UnstructuredPowerPointLoader(
    "<PATH TO PPT FILE>", mode="elements"
)
loaded_ppts = loader.load()
loaded_ppts = chromautils.filter_complex_metadata(loaded_ppts)

